# Oracle disconnect user on constrain

Tags: oracle, weblogic

My app deployed on weblogic 10.3, use a constraint for control some isert, but, from a few days ago, this is what happend when the constraint is thrown:

why oracle is disconnecting my weblogic pool user from database?

```
2014-04-01 14:07:20,047 - ERROR org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager - Commit exception overridden by rollback exception
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Could not execute JDBC batch update; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:609)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:717)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:586)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:662)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:632)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:314)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy97.save(Unknown Source)
    at -core.operaciones.OperacionObtenerFacturasProformaPdtesLeer.registrarFacturaProforma(OperacionObtenerFacturasProformaPdtesLeer.java:100)
    at -core.operaciones.OperacionObtenerFacturasProformaPdtesLeer.execute(OperacionObtenerFacturasProformaPdtesLeer.java:53)
    at -core.operaciones.AbstractGenericOperacion.execute(AbstractGenericOperacion.java:111)
    at -core.procesos.AbstractGenericProceso.execute(AbstractGenericProceso.java:63)
    at -util.LanzaProcesos.doPost(LanzaProcesos.java:76)
    at -util.LanzaProcesos.doGet(LanzaProcesos.java:188)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:180)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.doIt(WebAppServletContext.java:3684)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3650)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2268)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2174)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1446)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:578)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Io exception: Size Data Unit (SDU) mismatch
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwBatchUpdateException(DatabaseError.java:629)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:9467)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:211)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:246)
    ... 40 more
<Apr 1, 2014 2:07:20 PM CEST> <Error> <JDBC> <BEA-001112> <Test "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL" set up for pool "OracleDS" failed with exception: "java.sql.SQLException: Closed Connection".>
```

Thanks

Comment: This "*Io exception: Size Data Unit (SDU) mismatch*" looks like a network problem.

Comment: Lots of hits on it, what have you tried to fix it? https://community.oracle.com/thread/2127102?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Nothing in particular, this error, in my opinion, is a consecuence of an bad configuration of oracle user, my application controls the Oracle's constraint by exception capture.